# Installing Helm chart locally: “Error: gzip: invalid header”

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

> cat configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: product-api-configmap
data:
  myvalue: "Hello World"
```

> helm install ./configmap.yaml

`Error: gzip: invalid header`

Answer (score 2):

Change directory out of templates and the chart directory and then do

> helm install ./CHARTNAME

Comment: What if it returns the same error? What is idea behind running install command?